FileZilla Pro CLI - override the prompt if the file exists
When using Pro CLI in Powershell I need to override the prompt if the file exists when doing a 'put'. I have the following but still get the prompt, is this correct?
$scriptContent = @"
open sftp://${ftpUser}:${ftpPass}@${ftpHost}:22
lcd $localDirectory
option cli.prompt.file_exists:6
"@


Get-ChildItem -Path $localDirectory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
         $relativePath = $_.FullName.Substring($localDirectory.Length) -replace "\\", "/"
        $remoteDirPath = "./$relativePath"
        $scriptContent += "mkdir $remoteDirPath" + "`n"
    } else {
        
        $localFile = $_.FullName -replace "\\", "/"
        $relativePath = $_.DirectoryName.Substring($localDirectory.Length) -replace "\\", "/"
        $remoteFilePath = if ($relativePath) { "./$relativePath/" + $_.Name } else { "./" + $_.Name }
        
        $scriptContent += "nput `"$localFile`" `"$remoteFilePath`"" + "`n"

    }
}

I have also tried using the option to only put the file if it is newer or a different size, but this does not seem to work either.
$scriptContent += "put -e:size_newer  `"$localFile`" `"$remoteFilePath`"" + "`n"


Isn't there a newline missing between the first 3 commands and the put command? Try $scriptContent += "nput ..."`

Thanks for the reply @MathiasR.Jessen, that did remove the prompt but did not upload files not existing on remote, I've updated the post with the full block from the script

Sorry, the comment auto-formatting swallowed the code - you need a literal newline before the put command, eg. $scriptContent += "`nput..."

Thanks for clarifying, still getting the prompt unfortunately. I need to look into it more as the option to override is correct according to the documentation

For anyone interested, changing the line with the put command to this fixed it
$scriptContent += "put --exists size_newer `"$localFile`" `"$remoteFilePath`"" + "`n"


You can also set the file_exists option: set cli.file_exists size_newer.
